# WordPress sql injection

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-injection

Thanks for letting me post here, I'm just starting to learn programming.

I have a problem with a WordPress site which I update for my dad's local motorcycle road safety training group, which is run as a charity/non-profit by volunteer instructors. The hosting company (LCN) has taken the site down and emailed the group the following:

---

> Domain name : kamg.org.uk
> Database : kamg_org_uk_dbtest
> MySQL Server : database3.lcn.com
>
> Our monitoring scripts have detected an SQL injection attack occurring on your web site kamg.org.uk, using exploitable code hosted there.
>
> The SQL queries that have been flagged as suspicious/malicious are listed here :
>
> ----- BEGIN REPORT -----
>
> TIME RUNNING: 01:34:02
> SELECT `wp_users`.`ID`, `wp_users`.`user_login`, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key`, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` FROM `wp_users` INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` ON `wp_users`.`user_login` = "" OR CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 0x255f7573657273) THEN sleep(5) ELSE 0 END AND "1"="1" AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` LIKE "%_user_level" AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` = "10" AND `wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_usermeta`.user_id
>
> TIME RUNNING: 01:34:00
> SELECT `wp_users`.`ID`, `wp_users`.`user_login`, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key`, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` FROM `wp_users` INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` ON `wp_users`.`user_login` = "" OR CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 0x255f7573657273) THEN sleep(5) ELSE 0 END AND "1"="1" AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` LIKE "%_user_level" AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` = "10" AND `wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_usermeta`.user_id
>
> ----- END REPORT -----

WP, plugins and theme are all kept up to date at all times.

Can I safely just delete those lines from the database to clean the site?

LCN offer the group free charity hosting but I have found over 1600 domains share the same server. Once the sql injection is cleaned the group will move to managed WP hosting in the hope it will be more secure.

Thx,

Niels

I have tried reinstalling WordPress by FTP, but the hosts have denied the attempt, having removed all permissions.

Their support is appalling, taking 4 days to respond to queries, and then answering the wrong question with a cut & paste stock response.

I have just started learning, but I'd be happy to go in and edit files (with some nervousness) but haven't attempted anything at this stage.

Comment: Those are not lines in DB to be deleted. Your hosting is detecting attack and monitors what is the sql query. This current attack is targeting information_schema table - what is this you can find short answer here - https://eu.siteground.com/kb/what_is_the_information_schema_database/ . Most companies provide tools to scan and locate if there is infected files or its just remote attempt of attack. Move your website to a hosting providing better protection and are known for better support. OR install fresh wordpress and move your content there.

Comment: Also if you use mass used theme attackers could target all websites that use this theme and know for vulnerability. Same rule is for plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the data that is at fault, it's something in the code of WordPress, or more likely one of the plugins or themes you have installed.

The way the code works is something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_login, wp_usermeta.meta_key,
  wp_usermeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.user_login = "' . $variable . 
  '" AND wp_usermeta.meta_key LIKE "%_user_level" AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = "10" 
  AND wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id';
```

But the value of `$variable` has been exploited by some attacker. They set it to the following string:

```
" OR CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 0x255f7573657273) THEN sleep(5) ELSE 0 END AND "1"="1
```

(even including the quote characters.)

When the variable is concatenated into the query, it causes the SQL query to have extra expression terms, that the attacker injected.

It looks like they're forcing `sleep()` calls to test if certain tables exist. They'll use this method to learn all your table names. Then they'll use information in subsequent attacks, to read those tables. SQL injection hackers have to probe using techniques like this to try to avoid detection.

The original query may be a normal part of the code of WordPress or one of the plugins or themes. But the programmer made a mistake by concatenating a variable whose value was set from untrusted input. Programmers aren't supposed to do this, but many are either unaware of the risk, or else they think it won't happen to their code.

You said you are up to date on all the versions of WordPress and plugins, but the vulnerability may exist in the current version. In other words, no newer version with a fix has been released (yet).

Sometimes it doesn't help to update the software, because the newest version has introduced a *new* vulnerability that didn't exist before. Programmers add new code in every version, and security vulnerabilities are the result of mistakes made by software developers. New vulnerabilities occur regularly.

WordPress itself is pretty well tested, that's why I suppose the vulnerability may be in a plugin or theme. I don't know which plugins you use.

Or you may have added custom code that has the vulnerability, so there is no other person who will update it. It's up to you.

What you have to do now is figure out which line of *code*, not data, is responsible for the vulnerability. If you don't have the skills to do this (basically a text search across many files to find a line of code similar to the one I showed above), then you need to employ someone to help you.

Once you find the line of code responsible, either fix it yourself, or if it's in a plugin you could just uninstall that plugin to remove the vulnerable code.

It sounds like your hosting company isn't going to help. They probably have very little resources to provide customer service in this case. Even if you fix the code, it sounds like it will be a struggle to get them to allow you to restore your website.

You may need to find a new hosting provider if your current one won't communicate or let you have access to your site.

But a different hosting provider won't be more secure, because the fault is not with the hosting provider. The fault is in the code you are using.

If you install the same code on the current provider or another provider without fixing it, the code will still be vulnerable to hacks. If you upload code you know is vulnerable, then it'll be your fault.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to go into this Bill, very much appreciated :)

Funnily enough we have asked someone to look into this, who coincidentally had noticed the question here.

I'll post back with the outcome soon.

Thanks again,

Niels